# Approve record through email: from/Reply address has only current user email address

Tags: api, approval-process

i am implementing the approval process where the user will approve/Reject through email only.

I have enabled all the required configuration in Sandbox (Developer Pro).

- Enabled 'Enable Email Approval Response' in approval Settings.
- User profiles are API enabled
- I have assigned proper email templates

when i have submitted the record for approval process. approvers getting email notifications, if the user replies to the email with 'Approve' it is not reflecting in the saleforce record.

i noticed that the reply email address is not the service email address which normally generated for approval process email notifications.

Can someone help me to identify the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the approval process has manual approver selection or approver as a Queue, then email approval process will be available. Any alternatives? since 2 approvers can approve in any order.

Comment: If email approval response is enabled, the user can alternatively reply to the email by typing approve, approved, yes, reject, rejected, or no in the first line of the email body, and adding comments in the second line.  can you try with small caps and make sure its first line of body and comments on second line .

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue myself - if the recipient/approver has an email domain other than the email domain of the sender of the approval request, SFDC won't allow email approvals by that recipient.

For example, you may have email forwarding going on in your mail server so that emails sent to   joe@foo.com are forwarded to joe@bar.com; Joe@bar.com won't get the SFDC built-in reply custom address.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that the 'approver' must reply using the same email address that received the approval email otherwise the email response approval process will not work. As I see it, the approving email address is treated more like an external id with a corresponding API enabled for it to access the saleforce app. Changing the approver's email would mean breaking this rule and would cause security/authentication issues. It is why a queue is not allowed either.